# "Undefined variable from import" Earth Engine and Python API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, import

I'm writing some code for a GEE Application and I want to calculate the area of pixels in a given area.
I've found this method:

```py
areas = (imNDVI4.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion(reducer = ee.Reducer.sum(), geometry = test2, scale=10))
```

Unfortunately, I'm unable to run this part because of this error:

> ***Undefined variable from import: ...***

that pops up both on **pixelArea**() and **Reducer** methods.

How could I solve this issue?

---

P.S. My "earthengine-api" package is already up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I personally solved this issue after an aid from a friend of mine. The problem is not due to Python itself but by its interpreter.

So, if you're using Eclipse follow this procedure:
**Window > Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Code Analysis > Undefined > Undefined variable from import > Ignore**

This is also quite useful if you want to not show those boring warnings from unused imports. The procedure is just the same, only change the selected tab.